# Permissions to run any app

Tags: kiosk-mode

I am looking for possibility to run only:

- phone
- chrome
- camera
- music player

on Android device. I want to check app first before I decide to give permission to run it. I want to run Phone app but I want to block SMS app and all other messaging apps.

How can I set it up ?

The purpose is to give the smartfone to the kid but with very limited options, so it's not using messaging and other chat apps , the only way of communication is just phone call but also I want her to have a Web Browser and phone Contact list, Camera and some Music apps so she can use it as a player anytime.

No distracting apps loaded with ads, no texting, no notifications.

Please help with the simplest solution for that.

Thank you

Comment: What you're after is called "kiosk mode" (I've adjusted your tags accordingly). There are specific "[app-lockers](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/security_applocker#group_451)" for that you could check with. Not sure if the on-board functionality of "restricted profiles" would suffice for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use kiosk mode for that. The simplest way to set up kiosk-mode on Android is to use Google's [Android Management API](https://developers.google.com/android/management/) which works for any Android devices running Android 5.1 or above.

To lock the device on one app, or on multiple app, you define a kiosk policy like below, it will disable the navigation buttons (sample copied from [Create a policy](https://developers.google.com/android/management/create-policy#for_devices_running_multiple_apps_from_a_custom_launcher)):

```
"applications": [
 {
   "packageName": "com.example.app",
   "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
   "lockTaskAllowed": true,
   "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT",
 },
"persistentPreferredActivities": [
  {
    "receiverActivity": "com.example.app/.com.example.app.MainActivity",
    "actions": [
      "android.intent.action.MAIN"
    ],
    "categories": [
      "android.intent.category.HOME",
      "android.intent.category.DEFAULT"
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Hi Fred! We are an end-user oriented site so we naturally expect answers catering to such users only. Please visit [help] for more information.

Comment: May I ask you to paste here JSON with settings for this API and tell me where should I place it in my device ? The settings should only run those 5 apps I mention in my questions.  Thank you in advance.